# LazyVGrid not animating with Realm Objects

Tags: swiftui, realm

I have created a grid of show cards, consisting of an image and a name, which is populated by the results of a Realm query. However, when I attempt to delete an object from the Realm database, I expect it to animate its removal, but instead, it simply disappears. I have tried using a normal Realm write transaction but still have not achieved the desired outcome. The ShowResult type conforms to the ObjectKeyIdentifiable protocol.

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
struct MainScreen: View {
    var columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 2)

    @ObservedResults(ShowResult.self) var storedShows
    @Environment(\.realm) var realm

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("Primary")
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(storedShows) { show in
                        ShowCard(show: show)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    $storedShows.remove(show)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(20)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `ShowCard` do? Do you want a specific animation? Not sure of your Swift/XCode version but did you try `withAnimation(.default)`?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to put the animation on the Zstack container :

```
struct MainScreen: View {
var columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 20), count: 2)

@ObservedResults(ShowResult.self) var storedShows
@Environment(\.realm) var realm

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color("Primary")
            .ignoresSafeArea()

        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(storedShows) { show in
                    ShowCard(show: show)
                        .onTapGesture {
                               $storedShows.remove(show)
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding(20)
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.4),value: storedShows)
    }
}
```

}